# How is electron richness defined?

Tags: electronic-configuration

What does it mean for an atom/molecule to be electron rich? For instance, why is the methyl carbanion considered electron rich (having excess electrons) even though it has a complete octet, no more, no less? I know that if the octet is incomplete, an atom/molecule is considered electron deficient, but how exactly is electron richness defined? I was under the impression that electron richness referred to atoms/molecules which had more than 8 electrons on the central atom.

Comment: These are just wording used by organic chemists. It has nothing to do with reality. What is experimentally realizable is the electron density by X-ray measurements. The rest is all hand-waving spam.

Comment: It is electron rich as it still has electrons to spare for bond formation.

Comment: Like temperature, without established reference, there is no comparison possible.  A reasonable comparison would be like «There are more $\pi$ electrons per non-H atom in pyrrole than in benzene; thus the $\pi$ electron density in pyrrole is higher than the one in benzene and considered electron rich.»  If not reformulated, the question will attract opinions instead of answers backed by evidence.